# How do I Nginx rewrite with query?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

how do I rewrite this url from:

```
mysite.com/folder1/file.php?kw=KEYWORD
```

to

```
mysite.com/folder1/file/KEYWORD
```

and

```
mysite.com/folder1/single.php?sname=hoover-firestarter-freemusic&vid=EawzHfX4n30
```

into

```
mysite.com/folder1/single/hoover-firestarter-freemusic
```

Please help me out, and thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
location ~* ^/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)\.php$ {
  if ($arg_kw) {
    return 302 $scheme://$server_name/$1/$2/$arg_kw;
  }
  if ($arg_sname) {
    return 302 $scheme://$server_name/$1/$2/$arg_sname;
  }
}
```